# Hashing complexity regarding the no of searches in worst case

Tags: hash

A hash table has a size of 11 and date is fitted in postion {3,5,7,9,6} how many comparisons have to be made if data is not found in the list in worst case 2,11,6

Comment: You should probably ask this on the Programmers Stack Exchange: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

That depends a lot on how the terminology's intended and the hash table implementation...

- "a hash table of size 11" might mean 11 elements (especially in C++ where `.size()` is the function for finding out how many elements are in the table), or 11 buckets, but in this case probably means the latter;
- "data is fitted" might be intended to mean there's a single datum (the singular of data) in each of those bucket positions, or it might mean there could be one or more (but if the latter's intended and "size" isn't the number of buckets, there's no answer).
- "how many comparisons" normally means key-vs-key comparisons, but the implementation will need to perform comparisons of bucket content against no-[more]-value sentinels too
- the implementation might handle collisions using a list of colliding keys per bucket, or it might rehash or cascade/jump through some set of offsets (a displacement list) from the hashed-to-bucket

So, if we assume 11 buckets, that there's only one data item at each bucket position `{3,5,7,9,6}` and key-on-key comparisons, and nominally lists of colliding elements per bucket, then the worst that can happen is a comparison against a buckets with an existing entry, which means a key-on-key comparison then a key-vs-sentinel comparison.  That could satisfy the "2" answer.

If the system uses displacement lists or rehashing, there's generally no protection against visiting the same bucket several times (it's just statistically unlikely), so there is no "worst case" limit short of the implementation giving up.

If the specific dead simple case that the displacement increments to try the next bucket, it might give up after visiting a string of populated buckets and finding the first empty one... given `{3,5,7,9,6}` the worst case is that it compares keys at 5 then 6 then 7 then compares against a sentinel at 8, for 3 or 4 total comparisons depending on how you count it.

If the size indicates the number of elements, such that 11 are spread across `{3,5,7,9,6}` which would only be possible if any individual bucket maintained a list of colliding keys, then if 4 of those buckets had a single key, the remaining bucket might have 11-4 = 7, so there could be 7 key-on-key comparisons before failure.

It's very hard to imagine any reasonable interpretation of the question yielding 6 or 11 comparisons, by any counting method.

If someone's asked you this in an academic setting, there might be some specific implementation and notational conventions you can apply when considering the question.  If such context is missing, whomever's asking is either very lazy or not very well versed in even the basics of hash tables.